# Why can't One class's Status change convey to Other Classes when Writing a Qt Graphics VIew program

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem

when Using Qt Graphics View to simulate traffic situation.

I have :

- 2 global class `TrafficLight` inherited from `QGraphicsItem`
- class `Car` inherited from `QGraphicsItem`

  ```
  class TrafficLight : public QGraphicsItem
  {
    public:

      TrafficLight( int sec );
      QColor getLightStatus( ELightDirct ) volatile;

      QRectF boundingRect() const;
      void paint( QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem* option,
              QWidget* Widget );
      QPainterPath shape() const;


    protected:
      void advance( int step );

    private:
      volatile int ticker;

    public:
      volatile bool ableNS;


  };


  static TrafficLight* pLightAtCr1 = new TrafficLight( 0 );

  static TrafficLight* pLightAtCr2 = new TrafficLight( 125 );
  ```

And in the `advance()` function of TrafficLight, counting and change `ticker` and `ableNS` status:

```
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*                                 advance                                   */
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void TrafficLight::advance( int step )
{
    if ( !step )
        return;

    if ( ticker == 140 * freq / speedUp - 1)
    {
        ticker = 0;
        ableNS = false;
    }
    else if ( ticker == 120 * freq -1 )
    {
        ++ticker;
        ableNS = true;

    }
    else 
    {
        ++ticker;
    }
}
```

Then the Car class :

```
class Car: public QGraphicsItem
{
    public:
        Car();
            Car( EPlace, EPlace, qreal );

        QRectF boundingRect() const;
        void paint( QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option,
                QWidget *widget );

        QPainterPath shape() const;
        void setStartPos();

        bool ableToForward( TrafficLight*, ELightDirct ) const;
        void checkLightForward() ;


    protected:
        void advance( int step );

    public:
        EPlace genPlace;
        EPlace dist;
        qreal speed;


     };
```

void Car::checkLightForward() function check global traffciLight's status and determine stop to wait or moving at every advance.

```
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*                                 checkLightForward                         */
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void Car::checkLightForward() 
{
    QPointF curLoc = mapToScene( 0, 0 );
    if ( curLoc == lightCr1BSN || curLoc == lightCr1BSS ) {
            if ( !pLightAtCr1->ableNS ) {
                }
            else {
                setPos( mapToParent( 0, 0.5 ) );
            }
    }
    else {
        setPos( mapToParent( 0, 0.5 ) );
    }
}
```

at the `Car::advance()`, invoke the `checkLightForward()`.

and added them to `QGraphicsScene`.
Then the `main()`

```
QTimer timer;
QObject::connect( &timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), &scene, SLOT(advance()) );
timer.start( 1000/freq );
```

But what make me confused:

`TrafficLight pLightAtCr1` status changed that can be seen on `QGraphicsView`, but cars can not
received the TrafficLight's status changes, ignoring red Light.

does compiler optimization lead to this confused result, that storing TrafficLight's status in the register. Or other reason? How can I fix this problem!

and merry christmas~
thanks so much!